# Running headers in the margin

Tags: header-footer, marginpar

How do I create a running header that appears in the margin instead of in the header? The following MWE produces the sort of running text I want in the header. I would like to replace the `\def` lines with something like `\def\@oddhead{\marginpar{\thepage \\ \rightmark:\leftmark}}`. The correct version of this would make two-line running text in the margin.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{\thepage \hfill \rightmark:\leftmark}
\def\@evenhead{\thepage \hfill \rightmark:\leftmark}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {0,...,12}{\markboth{\n}{\n}\blindtext\par}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? I've added (commented in the preamble) a code which uses `fancyhdr`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
 \makeatletter
 \def\@oddhead{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{\marginparsep}\raisebox{-\dimexpr\headsep+\height+\smallskipamount\relax}{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\centering\rightmark:\leftmark\\\thepage}}}}
 \def\@evenhead{\llap{\raisebox{-\dimexpr\headsep+\height+\smallskipamount\relax}%
{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\centering\rightmark:\leftmark\\\thepage}\hspace{\marginparsep}}\hfill}}
 \makeatother%

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {0,...,12}{\markboth{\n}{\n}\blindtext\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok :-) i'll delete comments, (not usefull for other users)

Comment: Your answer shows how to produce running text that is in the margins of the header. I am looking for something that produces two lines in the same margin of the body text whose top is the same as the top of the body text.

Comment: @louis: I've misunderstood what you want, it seems. I'll change my answer in a moment.

Comment: @louis: I've updated my answer. If you want to do that with `fancyhdr`, comment the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, and uncomment the commented lines in the preamble.

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for the great answer. Both options are closer to what I desire. The first option (as is) still includes a page number at the bottom of each page, which is undesirable. Both options produce running text above the body text instead of top-aligned to it. Can this approach be modified to include top-aligning, too?

Comment: I'll  propose a solution in a moment. For the page numbers in the footer, add to the preamble  `\pagestyle{myheadings}`.

Comment: @louis: I've uodated my answer. Is is what you want?

Comment: @Bernard, this is just what I want! Do you know of any resources that could help me better understand the lengths you use? For example, if I had wanted to determine the amount of vertical space needed for the first argument to `\raisebox`, what resource would allow me to look up `\headsep+\height+\smallskipamount`?

Comment: For the layout dimensions, look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout). `\height` is the height of the contents that's being raised (it may also have a `depth`) and `\smallskipamount` is a fraction of the interline skip, for adjustment (more or less by trial and errors). If you want to  understand better what's involved here, add `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` ,  `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}` , remove `+\smallskipamount`, put `\raisebox`in a `\fbox{…}` and compile.